# How to trim and escape a string pointer in golang?

Tags: go

Username is not required and it can be nil, so I made this property pointer to string.

```
type User struct {
    Username *string `json:"username"`
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

func (u *User) PrepareUser() {
    if u.Username != nil {
        u.Username = html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(u.Username))
    }
    u.Email = html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(u.Email))
    u.Password = strings.TrimSpace(u.Password)
}
```

When trying to trim and escape I see "cannot use html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(u.Username)) (value of type string) as *string value in assignment"

Comment: As a bit of an aside, it's not uncommon in Go to use empty strings (as well as the default value for other types) as the "null value", especially in cases where an empty string would almost always be an invalid value otherwise. This makes it a lot easier to use the value when it is populated. The `omitempty` JSON flag goes well with this. It's certainly not your only option - but it does keep things easier when you don't have to constantly nil check and deference the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func trimEscapeStrPtr(s *string) *string {
    t := html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(*s))
    return &t
}
```

[better example here](https://play.golang.org/p/4vYECnAdABg)

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the value of pointer via `*` operator.

```
html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(*u.Username))
```

**Update**

Also don't forget to use `*` operator for assigning value

```
*u.Username = html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(*u.Username))
```